# How to predict next word using Embedding

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp

I want to predict the next word in Tensorflow. Before, I was saving one vector for each word as much as all the unique words, but this takes up a lot of memory, so I want to use embedding for this, but I'm a little confused about the dimensions of the vectors because in this method We use Integer numbers instead of 0 and 1.

I wrote this code:

```
# previous_words_list is a list of 5 consecutive words (inputs)
# next_words is a list of the sixth word in each word sequence (labels)
words_length_embedded = 50
number_of_previous_words = 5
inputs = np.zeros((len(previous_words_list), number_of_previous_words), dtype=float)
labels = np.zeros((len(next_words), len(unique_words)), dtype=float)
print(inputs.shape)
print(labels.shape)
for i, each_words in enumerate(previous_words_list):
    for j, each_word in enumerate(each_words):
        inputs[i, j] =  unique_word_index[each_word]
    labels[i] = unique_word_index[next_words[i]]
# for example: "inputs" is: [[22,1,34,5,7], ...] and "labels" is: [44, ...]      ???????

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(len(unique_words), words_length_embedded, input_length=number_of_previous_words, trainable=True))
model.add(LSTM(256, input_shape=(number_of_previous_words, words_length_embedded), return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dense(len(unique_words)))    #  ???????
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
optimizer = 'adam'
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I know that input of Dense layer or inputs and labels dimensions is not true but what should these be?

Comment: Do you get any error message?

Comment: Yes I do. And this error is obvious because the dimensions of the dance layer do not match the dimensions of the labels, and my question is that I do not know what they should look like. (question marks in code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think everything is true except loss function. When you are using unique numbers for unique words Instead of one-hot vector for any unique words, you must use `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` instead of `categorical_crossentropy` for loss function:

```
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])
```